# Format microseconds as hours:minutes:seconds, etc

Tags: code-golf, date

The following is inspired by [a question that came up on Stack Overflow today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251377).

Given a number of microseconds, `0 <= n <= 86400000000` (e.g. `12345678900`), output a formatted string `hh:mm:ss:000:000`, e.g. `03:25:45:678:900`.

```
          0 -> '00:00:00:000:000'
12345678900 -> '03:25:45:678:900'
86400000000 -> '24:00:00:000:000'
```

I have a solution in Python in 209 bytes, but can it go lower?

Comment: I realise now that this isn't really a standard format for writing times, and `hh:mm:ss.000000` would probably have been better (and easier). Still, can't go changing it now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the SO post?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251377 by a relatively new user. A correct answer had already been chosen, I was just playing around in IDLE and came up with a grotesque-looking dictionary comprehension that wasn't a particularly good answer to the question. Someone saw it and pointed out this site in a comment. I came here, wrote a question (slightly different to the SO post), and also wrote a much improved version of my answer (which I haven't posted, and which is now redundant to all the much more compact and imaginative answers below).

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of hours in the input?

Comment: Yes, arbitrarily I made it <= 86400000000 microsec, so <= 24 hours.

Comment: Sure would have saved me quite a few characters in my JavaScript answer if ISO format with the dot was allowed :/ Interesting challenge nonetheless :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Answer (score 15):

## Python 2, <s>82</s> 79 bytes

```py
n=input()
o=""
for k in[1000]*2+[60]*3:o=":%0*d"%(k%7/2,n%k)+o;n/=k
print o[1:]
```

Builds the string, iterating through a series of divmods. The only fancy bit is the `%7/2`, which maps `1000 -> 3` and `60 -> 2`.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 31 bytes

```
j\:_m>l`td+"00"%~/QddCM"ϨϨ<<<
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C%3A_m%3El%60td%2B%2200%22%25~%2FQddCM%22%CF%A8%CF%A8%3C%3C%3C&input=12345678900&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
                                 implicit: Q = input number
                       "ϨϨ<<<   string "ϨϨ<<<" (5 chars but 7 bytes)
                     CM          convert each to number => [1000, 1000, 60, 60, 60]
    m                            map each number d to:
                 /Qd                divide Q by d
                ~                   and update Q with the new value
               %~ Q d               but use the old value to calculate Q mod d
          +"00"                     add the result to the string "00"
     >                              but only take the last 
      l`td                          len(str(d-1)) chars
   _                             revert order
j\:                              join the strings with ":"s
```

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + coreutils, 61

Shortest "mainstream" language so far...

```
a=%02d:
printf $a$a$a%03d:%03d `dc -e$1\ A00~rA00~r60~r60~rf`
```

#### Test output:

```
$ for t in 0 12345678900 86400000000; do ./usec.sh $t; echo; done
00:00:00:000:000
03:25:45:678:900
24:00:00:000:000
$
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>37 35</s> 34 bytes

This is prettty long .. Golfing now..

```
ri[1e3_60__]{:ImdsIBb,0e[':@}%W%2>
```

*UPDATE: 1 byte saved thanks to @Sp3000*

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%5B1e3_60__%5D%7B%3AImdsIBb%2C0e%5B%27%3A%40%7D%25W%252%3E&input=12345678900)

Answer (score 4):

## q (34)

I'm sure it can be shorter

```
":"sv 0 8 11__[;8]15$2_($)16h$1e3*
```

e.g.

```
q)f:":"sv 0 8 11__[;8]15$2_($)16h$1e3*
q)f 12345678900
"03:25:45:678:900"
```

Comment: any online compilers ? in other words - How do I run it as a lazy person ?

Comment: 32 bit version is available for free at http://www.kx.com

Comment: good spot. unfortunately the fix adds a few characters

Comment: you can cut more bytes here `":"sv 0 8 11__[;8]15$2_($)"n"$1e3*`

Answer (score 4):

## C, 97 bytes

```
q=1000,s=60;
#define f(n)printf("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d",n/s/s/q/q,n/s/q/q%s,n/q/q%s,n/q%q,n%q)
```

Test Code:

```
int main(int intc, char **argv)
{
    long long n = atoll(argv[1]);
    f(n);
}
```

Comment: Answers in C are supposed to be a complete, program; not a snippet.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the question. Is there some sort of global requirements?

Comment: [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1146/20748)

Comment: No. If you read the answer, it is just using C as an example. The rule would have applied to every language. Also, the answer is hotly disputed - see the highest rated comment. The bottom line is the Question needs to state it clearly if a full program is required.

Comment: It has 41 upvotes and 9 downvotes, it's very much enforceable. That being said, you're defining a "function" which is an acceptable way to create an answer, so I would argue that this is fine.

Comment: Lots of answers on this site use functions instead of full programs - for example I don't think I have ever seen a Java answer that was a complete program...

Comment: I tried this on ideone, it returns `03:00:25:000:045` for `12345678900`, which is incorrect.

Comment: I blame ideone. My code works fine with gcc on Linux and Mac. On ideone, even `printf("%d:%d", n/q%q, n%q);` ended up with `678:0`. (it should be `678:900`)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>179</s> 175 Bytes

When you have builtins at your disposal, why not use 'em?

```cs
static void Main(string[]a){var t=TimeSpan.FromTicks(long.Parse(Console.ReadLine())*10);Console.Write(t.ToString((t.Days<1?"hh":@"\2\4")+@"\:mm\:ss\:ffffff").Insert(12,":"));}
```

With better formatting:

```cs
static void Main(string[]a){
    var t = TimeSpan.FromTicks(long.Parse(Console.ReadLine())*10);
    Console.Write(t.ToString((t.Days<1?"hh":@"\2\4")+@"\:mm\:ss\:ffffff").Insert(12,":"));
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>110</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```matlab
t->(o="";for i=int([36e8,6e7,1e6,1e3,1]) x,t=t÷i,t%i;o*=lpad(x,i>1e3?2:3,0)*":"end;o[1:end-1])
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an integer as input and returns a string. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=t->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
function f(t)
    # Initialize an output string
    o = ""

    # Loop over an array consisting of the number of microseconds in
    # an hour, minute, second, millisecond, and microsecond
    for i = int([36e8, 6e7, 1e6, 1e3, 1])

        # Get the quotient and remainder for microseconds into t,
        # setting t to be the remainder
        x, t = t ÷ i, t % i

        # Left-pad x with zeroes and append it to the output
        o *= lpad(x, i > 1e3 ? 2 : 3, 0) * ":"
    end

    # o has a trailing :, so return everything but the last character
    o[1:end-1]
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f(12345678900)
"03:25:45:678:900"

julia> f(0)
"00:00:00:000:000"

julia> f(86400000000)
"24:00:00:000:000"
```

Comment: Nice one. You get my vote because you inspired my Matlab answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Excel, <strike>65</strike> 63 characters

Assuming your microseconds is in **A1**:

```
=TEXT(A1/50/1200^3,"[HH]:mm:ss:")&RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"000\:000"),7)
```

Output:

```
        A              B
1            0  00:00:00:000:000
2  12345678900  03:25:46:678:900
3  86400000000  24:00:00:000:000
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>141</s> 78 bytes

```
printf"%02d"x3.%03d:%03d",$_/36e8,$_/6e7%60,$_/1e6%60,$_/1e3%1e3,$_‌​%1e3
```

77 bytes of code, +1 for the `-n` flag.
Run with:

```
echo 12345678900 | perl -ne'printf"%02d"x3.%03d:%03d",$_/36e8,$_/6e7%60,$_/1e6%60,$_/1e3%1e3,$_‌​%1e3'
```

Thanks to Thomas Kwa and chilemagic for cutting my code size nearly in half.

Comment: I think `3600000000` can be `36e8`.

Comment: Instead of `chomp($n=<STDIN>);` you can run it as a one-liner with the `-n` flag (which counts as 1 character). You also don't need the `int(..)` around each `$_`. Applying Thomas's tip too we can get it down to `echo 12345678900 | perl -ne'printf"%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d\n",$_/36e8,$_/6e7%60,$_/1e6%60,$_/1e3%1e3,$_%1e3'` and there might even be a shorter way too!

Comment: You don't need the `\n` in the output string either. You can also replace the string with `"%02d:"x3 ."%03d:%03d"`

Comment: @chilemagic Does using "echo" count as an increase in bytes?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI it doesn't because it isn't part of your program. The characters you would count are the ones between the single quotes, i.e. `printf"%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d\n",$_/36e8,$_/6e7%60,$_/1e6%60,$_/1e3%1e3,$_‌​%1e3` and then you add an additional byte for the `-n` flag. If you used `-nle` for example, that would count as an additional 2 (for the `n` and the `l`). You get the `-` and the `e` (or `E` if you need to use `say`) for free.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>128</s> <s>118</s> <s>116</s> 111 bytes

There is probably some golfing potential in this.

```js
f=t=>(t<864e8?new Date(t/1e3).toJSON().slice(11,-1):`24:00:00:000`).replace(`.`,`:`)+':'+('00'+t%1e3).slice(-3)
```

#### Demo

It is ES6 so Firefox only, for now anyways:

```js
f=t=>(t<864e8?new Date(t/1e3).toJSON().slice(11,-1):`24:00:00:000`).replace(`.`,`:`)+':'+('00'+t%1e3).slice(-3)

// DEMO
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + f(0);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + f(12345678020);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + f(86400000000);
```

Comment: The first check is not needed, as the question is explicit: 0 <= n <= 86400000000

Comment: @edc65 Without the first check I can only get a range of 0 ≤ n < 86400000000, as 8.64e10 would roll over to the next day.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that. toJSON() instead of toISOString()?

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript, 127 bytes

Took the approach in [ASCIIThenANSI's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52686/22867). It's too bad that the JavaScript [Console API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api) doesn't have format placeholders for padding numbers.

```coffee
p=(a,b)->('00'+~~a).slice -b||-2
f=(t)->console.log '%s:%s:%s:%s:%s',p(t/36e8),p(t/6e7%60),p(t/1e6%60),p(t/1e3%1e3,3),p t%1e3,3
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab - 88 <s>89</s> bytes

Gained one byte with a solution without using the built in function:

```
n=[36e8,6e7,1e6,1e3];f=@(t)sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d',fix([t mod(t,n)]./[n 1]))
```

Create an inline function which takes a numeric input argument `t` and return a string.

it uses a vectorized combination of `fix` and `mod` to separate the time elements, then display.

it's a bit frustrating that the formatting of the output string takes so much, more than the calculations themselves ...

Test:

```
for t=[0 12345678900 86400000000]
    f(t)
end

ans =
00:00:00:000:000
ans =
03:25:45:678:900
ans =
24:00:00:000:000
```

---

89 bytes version:

```
f=@(t)sprintf('%s:%03d:%03d',datestr(fix(t/1e6)/86400,13),fix(mod(t,1e6)/1e3),mod(t,1e3))
```

It splits the number, uses a built-in function for the hh:mm:ss part, which cannot deal with microseconds so the string is completed with combination of `fix` and `mod` operations

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>113</s> <s>103</s> 105 bytes

*EDIT: shoved off some more bytes*

*FIX: removed long type, thanks to some user*

Not the shortest C answer, but I had some fun with carriage returns so I felt like someone might like this.

```
i,k,p=16;
#define f(n)for(;i<5;p-=i++<2?4:3)k=i<2?1000:60,printf("%0*d%c\r",p,n%k,i?58:13),n/=k;puts("");
```

Call it like:

```
int main() {
    long long n = 12345678900;
    f(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on platform, "long" could be just 32-bits. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). I avoided the problem by declaring "f" as macro instead of function.

Comment: I noticed that. I assumed GCC on x64, fixing it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

### Powershell,153

```
$t=[timespan]::FromTicks(($a=$args[0]));"{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}:{4:000}"-f
[int]($t.TotalHours),$t.Minutes,$t.Seconds,$t.Milliseconds,(($a%1e4)/10)
```

### Usage

```
powershell -nologo .\modprintsec.ps1 123456789000    
03:25:45:678:900   
powershell -nologo .\modprintsec.ps1 864000000000   
24:00:00:000:000   
powershell -nologo .\modprintsec.ps1 0   
00:00:00:000:000
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, <strike>111 92</strike> 102 bytes

First iteration: Base idea.

Second iteration: Smaller constants

Third iteration: Correct formatting for single digit portions.

Note this function must be given an int64 to work.

```
let s,t=60L,1000L
let f n=sprintf"%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d"(n/s/s/t/t)(n/s/t/t%s)(n/t/t%s)(n/t%t)(n%t)
```

Example outputs:

```
f 0L           -> "00:00:00:000:000"
f 12345678900L -> "03:25:45:678:900"
f 86400000000L -> "24:00:00:000:000"
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - <strike>115</strike> 102 bytes

A solution in 155 bytes (wrapped here on 3 lines for readability):

```
$a=$argv[1];
$h=($a-($m=($a=($a-($s=($a=($a-($t=($a=($a-($u=$a%1000))/1000)%1000))/1000)%60))/60)%60))/60;
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d",$h,$m,$s,$t,$u);
```

The second line computes (from inside to outside) the exact values of the components starting with the microseconds.

### The shorter version (115 bytes, wrapped on two lines for readability):

```
$u=$argv[1];$h=($m=($s=($t=$u/1000)/1000)/60)/60;
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d",$h,$m%60,$s%60,$t%1000,$u%1000);
```

It also uses embedded assignments to compute the convert the input number of microseconds in milliseconds, seconds, minutes and hours using floating point numbers. The modulus operator (`%`) and the decimal number format (`%d`) of `printf()` is then used to force them to integer numbers (the fractional part is ignored).

### Another solution that uses the date functions (102 bytes)

```
$u=$argv[1];
echo gmdate("H:i:s",strtotime("@".substr($u,0,-6))),":",substr($u,-6,3),":",substr($u,-3);
```

The hours:minutes:seconds part is handled by the PHP date functions `gmdate()` and `strtotime()`, the milli- and micro-seconds are extracted as strings from the input value.

#### Usage:

```
$ php -r '$u=$argv[1];echo gmdate("H:i:s",strtotime("@".substr($u,0,-6))),":",substr($u,-6,3),":",substr($u,-3);' 7198898787; echo
01:59:58:898:787
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 215 bytes

```
String f(long n){return p(n/3600000000l,2)+":"+p(n/60000000%60,2)+":"+p(n/1000000%60,2)+":"+p(n/1000%1000,3)+":"+p(n%1000,3);}String p(long n,int i){String s=String.valueOf(n);while(s.length()<i){s="0"+s;}return s;}
```

Method `f` does some calculations on `n` to work out the hours, minutes etc. and delegates to method `p` to format each value correctly.

**Formatted:**

```
String f(long n) {
    return p(n / 3600000000l, 2) + ":" + p(n / 60000000 % 60, 2) + ":" 
            + p(n / 1000000 % 60, 2) + ":" + p(n / 1000 % 1000, 3) + ":" + p(n % 1000, 3);
}

String p(long n, int i) {
    String s = String.valueOf(n);
    while (s.length() < i) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public void demo() {
    long n = 12345678900l;
    System.out.println(f(n));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Ruby - 82 Bytes

```
puts (t=Time.at(0,gets.to_i)).strftime("%2H:%2M:%2S:%3L:#{(t.usec%1000).to_s.rjust(3,?0)}")
```

Comment: But I counted 91 bytes. It also only works in the UTC timezone.